# Изменённая сортировка sqlite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo, sqlite3

База данных имеет следующие строки:

```
A
B
C
D
...
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно вывести отсортированно значения, например чтобы какие-то поля были вначале или наоборот в конце, к примеру C, A, B, D или A, C, D, B

Comment: Думаю тут нужна будет либо дополнительная колонка( int) отвечающая за порядок и по ней сортировать, либо справочник  в котором будет эта колонка.

Comment: Используйте оператор case в предложении order by: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html